# How to accelerate the selection in the QTableView?

Tags: qt, codeigniter, qtableview

I use the MVC to show a bund of of filenames , and there are opertions of selecting all and dissecting all in the CTableView . The number of files may thousands , so , I write a thread to do these ,like:

```
for (int row = 0; row < m_ImgMgr->m_TableModel->rowCount(); row++)
    {


        //QtSleep(5);

        for (int column = 0; column < m_ImgMgr->m_TableModel->columnCount(); column++)
        {

            //LogLog( QString(" sel 1") ) ;
            m_ImgMgr->listImages2->selectionModel()->select(m_ImgMgr->listImages2->model()->index(row, column), QItemSelectionModel::Select);

        }

        //LogLog(QString(" sel 2"));

        m_ImgMgr->labelImageIndex->setText(QString::number(row+1) + QString("/") + QString::number(m_ImgMgr->m_TableModel->rowCount()));

        //LogLog(QString(" sel 3"));

    }
```

but consuming time is not acceptable . And if the number is very large , the operation seems become more and more slowly by the end of the loop , it can be seen by the count number displayed in the GUI .

I also tried like below:

```
    QItemSelection sel = m_ImgMgr->listImages2->selectionModel()->selection( ) ;

    QModelIndex topleft     = m_ImgMgr->listImages2->model()->index( 0 , 0 ) ;
    QModelIndex bottonright = m_ImgMgr->listImages2->model()->index(m_ImgMgr->m_TableModel->rowCount(), 3 ) ;

    sel.select( topleft  , bottonright ) ;
```

no funtional.

Comment: The second approach looks more reasonable to me. However the bottomright index isn't correct. It should be rather `...->index(m_ImgMgr->m_TableModel->rowCount() - 1, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QTableView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QWidget mainWid;
   QAbstractItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(&mainWid);
   model->insertColumns(0,4);
   model->insertRows(0,5000);
   for(int rowIter = 0, maxRow = model->rowCount();rowIter<maxRow;++rowIter){
       for(int colIter = 0, maxCol = model->columnCount();colIter<maxCol;++colIter){
           model->setData(model->index(rowIter,colIter),QStringLiteral("%1,%2").arg(rowIter+1).arg(colIter+1));
       }
   }
   QTableView* table = new QTableView(&mainWid);
   table->setModel(model);
   QPushButton* selectAllButton = new QPushButton(QStringLiteral("Select All"),&mainWid);
   QObject::connect(selectAllButton,&QPushButton::clicked,table,[table]()->void{
       const QItemSelection selec(table->model()->index(0,0),table->model()->index(table->model()->rowCount()-1,table->model()->columnCount()-1));
       table->selectionModel()->select(selec,QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
   });
   QVBoxLayout* mainLay = new QVBoxLayout(&mainWid);
   mainLay->addWidget(selectAllButton);
   mainLay->addWidget(table);
   mainWid.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

this is the solution ,thanks  VRonin @ forum.qt.io